# Trying to modify a menu with hook_menu_alter

Tags: 7, routes, hooks

What is the best way to add a link to the user menu for a menu defined in my custom module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement the [hook_menu()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) in your custom module, then clear the cache and you will see the link in the User menu (you need place the block for the User menu in a region).

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_menu() {
   $items = array();
   $items['/path'] = array(
   'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
   'menu_name' => 'user-menu',
   'title' => t('Title'),
  );
  return $items;
}
```